# Check if kiosk mode is enable ( Guided access)

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, kiosk-mode, guided-access

I have a reactnative application, i want to check if the user enable or not the kiosk mode (Guided Access)

How we can check if user has enable Kiosk mode programmatically ?

I found nothing on the internet, Any help will be apprecied

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I add on didFinishLaunchingWithOptions
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(guidedAccessStatusChanged) name:UIAccessibilityGuidedAccessStatusDidChangeNotification object:nil];

```
-(void) guidedAccessStatusChanged {

if (UIAccessibilityIsGuidedAccessEnabled()) {
  [Connexion consumeCallBackCompoTrainEnableAccess : @"true"];
}  else {
  [Connexion consumeCallBackConduiteEnableAccess : @"false"];
  
}
```

}

```
+ (void) consumeCallBackConduiteEnableAccess : (NSString *) hasAcess {

   if(callbackStockConduite != nil && callbackStockConsommedConduite == false && [hasAcess isEqualToString:@"false"]){

callbackStockConsommedConduite = true;
callbackStockConduite(@[hasAcess]);

}
```

}

This callbackStockConduite is used by reactnative